# Conditions for Method Reference Expression to be "exact"

Tags: java, generics, type-inference, method-reference, jls

Consider the following article from the JLS (§15.13.1)

> A method reference expression ending with Identifier is exact if it satisfies all of the following:
>
> - If the method reference expression has the form ReferenceType ::[TypeArguments] Identifier, then ReferenceType does not denote a raw type.
> - The type to search has exactly one member method with the name Identifier that is accessible to the class or interface in which the method reference expression appears.
> - This method is not variable arity (§8.4.1).
> - If this method is generic (§8.4.4), then the method reference expression provides
>   TypeArguments.

Consider the following code snippet:

```java
class Scratch {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scratch.funct(new ImplementingClass()::<Functional1>hitIt);
  }

  public static void funct(Functional1 a){}
  public static void funct(Functional2 a){}
}
interface Functional1 {<T> T hitIt();}
interface Functional2 {<T> T hitIt();}

class ImplementingClass{
  public <T> T hitIt(){return null;}
}
```

Clearly - this satisfies all the conditions being mentioned for a method reference to be exact.

**Not sure why still the method reference is in-exact in this particular case? Am I missing something here from the clause?**

### Solution :

Based on inputs from @Sweeper @DidierL and @Holger here what I summarized:

1. Both the functional interfaces have the **functionType** `<T> () -> T`
2. the method reference `…::<Functional1>hitIt` substitutes `T` with `Functional1`, so the resulting functional signature is `() -> Functional1` which does not match `<T> () -> T`.

Comment: What makes you think it is inexact?

Comment: On compiling this - I am getting the error message -: `reference to funct is ambiguous
  both method funct(Functional1) in Scratch and method funct(Functional2) in Scratch match`

Comment: I used this reference to understand the symptoms of Inexact Method given by the compiler -: http://blog.gilliard.lol/2017/10/23/Java-Inexact-Method-References.html

Comment: Note that a method declared like `<T> T hitIt()` is really a bad idea, because there will be no compile-time check on the caller’s side. It basically says “_I will guess and return whatever the caller expects, trust me_”. A few years ago [I faced an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30517768/525036) when migrating an application from Java 7 to 8, with a similar method causing a different, unrelated method to be called on the caller’s side. And I never found a general way to identify such cases.

Comment: @DidierL : your point is very valid - but just wanted to know how the **semantics of exact method** and procedure for **compile time declaration lookup** from the `identifier` in the method references takes place?

Comment: Following the discussion you had with @Sweeper under their (now deleted) answer, it was clear that this should not compile due to the `<T> T` method declaration in `Functional1`/`Functional2`, however changing the return type should make it compile while it does not. Could you update your question accordingly? It would also be worth adding the compiler error in the question itself.

Comment: FYI I just tested the code with that modification in Eclipse and it compiles and run properly, so I’d tend to think it’s a javac bug.

Comment: @DidierL That's very nice to know! I just tried to find a bug report for this, but there are so many search results...

Comment: @DidierL : great explanation for you analysis - so the bottom line you are highlighting is that for my question - the compilation should ideally succeed but only coz of javac bug, the `Scratch.funct(new ImplementingClass()::<Functional1>hitIt);`  is not able to uniquely resolve the correct function?

Comment: @theutonium.18 I have answered that below my answer, however you should still edit your question with the appropriate code modification (i.e. change `Functional1` and `Functional2`’s `hitIt()` method to return a concrete type), otherwise Sweeper’s answer remains valid, and these discussions become confusing.

Comment: Also, just curious: why so many questions about [tag:jls]? Are you implementing some kind of parser?

Comment: @Sweeper , @DidilerL : actually what I concluded from  Sweeper's answer is that since the return type of both the functional interfaces is generic type - as indicated by the snippet in my question above - the function type for this internally is `<T> () -> T` , but the compiler treats it as `()-> Object` - because of this, the method reference sees 2 `funct` definitions -: `funct(Functional1)` and `funct(Functional2)` - and since the same functional type `() -> Object` is applicable the compiler is unable to infer the correct function implementation to choose.

Comment: @Sweeper ,@DidilerL : so we need to add an explicit casting context for the type inference to choose the correct function definition to pick and remove the ambiguity.

Comment: @Sweeper ,@DidilerL - but as indicated from the program by Sweeper - even if I make the return types of the functional interfaces explicit - ie make sure that FunctionType of `Functional1 = ()-> void` and FunctionType of `Functional2=() -> String`  still - when I use the **method reference** of `public <T> T hitIt(){return null;}` - the ambiguity is still not getting removed.

Comment: @Sweeper ,@DidilerL : so based on Didiler's answer I am concluding the issue is happening because the compiler is  not able to correctly infer - `Scratch.funct(new ImplementingClass()::<String>hitIt);` seems like? - Folks is my understanding correct till now?

Comment: @Sweeper ,@DidilerL:  Please refer to this program that I modified based on Sweeper's comments - but still it showed ambiguity: `class Scratch {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scratch.funct(new ImplementingClass()::<String>hitIt); // Functional1
    Scratch.funct(new ImplementingClass()::<Integer>hitIt); // Functional2
  }

  public static void funct(Functional1 a){}
  public static void funct(Functional2 a){}
}
interface Functional1 { String hitIt();}
interface Functional2 { void hitIt();}

class ImplementingClass{
  public <T> T hitIt(){return null;}
}`

Comment: @Sweeper ,@DidilerL : folks is my understanding correct? will accept this answer once we have completed our discussion regarding the issue being in the compiler :P :D .

Comment: @theutonium.18 please edit your updated code into the question. For the current code, `new ImplementingClass()::<Functional1>hitIt` is not a valid method reference for neither `Functional1` nor `Functional2` because, as Sweeper explained, the method reference has the type `() -> Functional1` whereas both interfaces have functional type `<T> () -> T`, i.e. an instance of those interfaces should be able to generate any type, not just `Functional1`. (but it is true that the error reported by the compiler is incorrect since neither method should be selected).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a warning: IANAJL (IANAL for Java )

As far as I can tell, this should compile if you make the two interface methods non-generic, but it doesn’t. Let’s simplify the code as much as we can to reproduce the problem:

```
class Scratch {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scratch.funct(ImplementingClass::<Void>hitIt);
  }

  public static void funct(Functional1 a){}
  public static void funct(Functional2 a){}
}
interface Functional1 {Integer hitIt();}
interface Functional2 {String hitIt();}

class ImplementingClass{
  public static <T> Integer hitIt(){return null;}
}
```

The simplifications:

- the two interfaces now have non-generic methods
- `ImplementingClass.hitIt()` is now static and has a concrete return type (non-generic)

Now let’s analyze the call to check if it should compile. I put links to the Java 8 specs but they are very similar in 17.

### [15.12.2.1. Identify Potentially Applicable Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.1)

> A member method is potentially applicable to a method invocation if and only if all of the following are true:
>
> […]
>
> - If the member is a fixed arity method with arity *n*, the arity of the method invocation is equal to *n*, and for all *i* (1 ≤ *i* ≤ *n*), the *i*'th argument of the method invocation is *potentially compatible*, as defined below, with the type of the *i*'th parameter of the method.
>
> […]
>
> An expression is *potentially compatible* with a target type according to the following rules:
>
> […]
>
> - A method reference expression ([§15.13](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13)) is potentially compatible with a functional interface type if, where the type's function type arity is *n*, there exists at least one potentially applicable method for the method reference expression with arity *n* ([§15.13.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.1)), and one of the following is true:
>
>   - The method reference expression has the form *ReferenceType :: [TypeArguments] Identifier* and at least one potentially applicable method is i) `static` and supports arity *n*, or ii) not `static` and supports arity *n*-1.
>   - The method reference expression has some other form and at least one potentially applicable method is not `static`.

(this last bullet applies for the case of the question where the method reference uses a constructor invocation expression, i.e. a [*Primary*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8))

At this point, we only check for the arity of the method reference, so both `funct()` methods are potentially applicable.

### [15.12.2.2. Phase 1: Identify Matching Arity Methods Applicable by Strict Invocation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.2)

> An argument expression is considered pertinent to applicability for a potentially applicable method m unless it has one of the following forms:
>
> […]
>
> - An inexact method reference expression ([§15.13.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.1)).
>
> […]

This is the only bullet point in this list that could potentially match, however, as pointed in the question we have an *exact* method reference expression here. Note that if you remove the `<Void>`, this makes it an inexact method reference, and both methods should be applicable as per the next section:

> Let `m` be a potentially applicable method (§15.12.2.1) with arity *n* and formal parameter types `F`<sub>`1`</sub> ... `F`<sub>`n`</sub>, and let `e`<sub>`1`</sub>, ..., `e`<sub>`n`</sub> be the actual argument expressions of the method invocation. Then:
>
> […]
>
> - If `m` is not a generic method, then `m` is applicable by strict invocation if, for 1 ≤ *i* ≤ *n*, either `e`<sub>`i`</sub> is compatible in a strict invocation context with `F`<sub>`i`</sub> or `e`<sub>`i`</sub> is not pertinent to applicability.

However only the first `funct()` method declaration should be applicable by strict invocation. Strict invocation contexts are defined [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3), but basically they check if the type of the expression matches the type of the argument. Here the type of our argument, the method reference, is defined by section [15.13.2. Type of a Method Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.2) whose relevant part is:

> A method reference expression is compatible in an assignment context, invocation context, or casting context with a target type T if T is a functional interface type ([§9.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.8)) and the expression is congruent with the [function type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.9) of […] T.
>
> […]
>
> A method reference expression is *congruent* with a function type if both of the following are true:
>
> - The function type identifies a single compile-time declaration corresponding to the reference.
> - One of the following is true:
>
>   - The result of the function type is `void`.
>   - The result of the function type is R, and the result of applying capture conversion ([§5.1.10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10)) to the return type of the invocation type ([§15.12.2.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.6)) of the chosen compile-time declaration is R' (where R is the target type that may be used to infer R'), and neither R nor R' is `void`, and R' is compatible with R in an assignment context.

Here R would be `Integer` for `Functional1` and `String` for `Functional2`, while `R'` is `Integer` in both cases (since there is no capture conversion needed for `ImplementingClass.hitIt()`), so clearly the method reference is not *congruent* with `Functional2` and by extension not compatible.

`funct(Functional2)` should thus not be considered for applicability by strict invocation, and since only `funct(Functional1)` remains it should be selected.

It should be noted that Javac must select both methods in Phase 1, because only one phase can apply, and Phase 2 only uses *loose context* instead of *strict*, which just allows boxing operations, and Phase 3 then includes varargs, which is not applicable either.

Except if we consider that Javac somehow considers the method reference as congruent with `Functional2`, the only reason I see for selecting both methods is if it considered the method reference as *not pertinent for applicability* as specified above, which I can only explain if the compiler considers it as an inexact method reference.

### [15.12.2.5. Choosing the Most Specific Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5)

This is where the compilation fails. We should note that there is nothing here that would make the compiler select one method over the other. The applicable rule is:

> - m2 is not generic, and m1 and m2 are applicable by strict or loose invocation, and where m1 has formal parameter types S1, ..., Sn and m2 has formal parameter types T1, ..., Tn, the type Si is more specific than Ti for argument ei for all i (1 ≤ i ≤ n, n = k).
>
> […]
> A type S is more specific than a type T for any expression if S <: T ([§4.10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10)).

This appears to work properly: change `Functional2` to extend `Functional1` and it will compile.

> A functional interface type S is more specific than a functional interface type T for an expression e if T is not a subtype of S and one of the following is true (where U1 ... Uk and R1 are the parameter types and return type of the function type of the capture of S, and V1 ... Vk and R2 are the parameter types and return type of the function type of T):
>
> - If e is an explicitly typed lambda expression […]
> - If e is an exact method reference expression (§15.13.1), then i) for all i (1 ≤ i ≤ k), Ui is the same as Vi, and ii) one of the following is true:
>
>   - R2 is void.
>   - R1 <: R2.
>   - […]

This does not allow to disambiguate it either. However, changing `Functional2.hitIt()` to return `Number` should make `Functional1` more specific since `Integer <: Number`.

This still fails, which seems to confirm that the compiler does not consider it as an exact method reference.

Note that removing the `<T>` in `ImplementingClass.hitIt()` allows it to compile, independently of the return type of `Functional2.hitIt()`. Fun fact: you can leave the `<Void>` at the call site, the compiler ignores it.

Even stranger: if you leave the `<T>` and add more type arguments than required at the call site, the compiler still complains about the ambiguous call and not about the number of type arguments (until you remove the ambiguity). Not that this should make the method reference inexact, based on the above definition, but I would think [it should be checked first](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.1).

### Conclusion

Since the Eclipse compiler accepts it, I would tend to consider this as a Javac bug, but note that the Eclipse compiler is sometimes more lenient than Javac with respect to the specs, and some similar bugs have been reported and closed ([JDK-8057895](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8057895), [JDK-8170842](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8170842), …).

Comment: great explanation for you analysis - so the bottom line you are highlighting is that for my question - the compilation should ideally succeed but only coz of javac bug, the `Scratch.funct(new ImplementingClass()::<Functional1>hitIt);` is not able to uniquely resolve the correct function?

Comment: @theutonium.18 according to me the strict invocation rules should only select one method thanks to the exact method reference, so yes for my example here. In the original code of your question it shouldn’t compile as indicated by Sweeper in their deleted question.

Comment: @theutonium.18 I can not reproduce your described behavior. The code posted in your question does not compile, neither with javac nor with Eclipse. I tried different versions. It’s not even clear why you expect it to compile. Both, `Functional1` and `Functional2` have identical functional signatures, so there can’t be an exact method reference that unambiguously matches one of them. Your method reference `…::<Functional1>hitIt` does not what you seem to think. It substitutes `T` with `Functional1`, so the resulting functional signature is `() -> Functional1` which does not match `<T> () -> T`

Comment: @DidierL it’s counter-productive to answer a different question than asked. Especially when starting it with “*As far as I can tell, this should compile.*” and it’s not obvious to the reader that “*this*” does not refer to the code of the question, but the code within your answer which you described as “*Let’s simplify the code*” while it actually is an entirely different scenario. Now, the reader has to scroll all the way down to your comment to find out that “*the original code of your question … shouldn’t compile*”

Comment: @Holger yeah sorry about that – I was expecting an update to the question which didn’t come. At the same time I had already started to dig into the real problem and needed to put my notes somewhere. Note that the compiler error is _reference to funct is ambiguous   both method funct(Functional1) in Scratch and method funct(Functional2) in Scratch match_ when actually none should match in the original question since they are using exact references, so this answer is actually still treating the same error.

Comment: @DidierL when I use the question’s original code, I get `The type of hitIt() from the type ImplementingClass is Functional1, this is incompatible with the descriptor's return type: T` in Eclipse and `incompatible types: bad return type in method reference … Functional1 cannot be converted to T` with javac.

Comment: @Holger yes you get that as a second error but the first one is the ambiguity error. Also note that you get that second error as well in my code if you change the order of the `func()` methods or if you change `ImplementingClass.hitIt()` to return `String`