# Gradle Build problems in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

My colleague worked on a Android application on API 21 in Android Studio 1.4 with `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'`. Also, he used Java jdk1.7.0_75.

And now I need to continue the work on this project. But I'm having Android Studio 2.1.1 and want to work on API 22 or 23. My gradle version is `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'` and I'm using Java jdk1.8.0_91.

If I try to 'Run' the app on the same Android device as he did, I get this error:

```
  Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72100Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72100Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42100Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugShaders
:app:generateDebugAssets
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).

C:\Users\z565719\AndroidStudioProjects\DrescherBluetoothCanCom\app\src\main\java\z550583\com\navigationdrawer\ConnectFragment.java:133: error: incomparable types: Object and int
        if (data.get(userDatabaseAdapter.ACCESS_NAME) == 1) {
                                                      ^


[24 more errors like the one above...]


                                                      ^
Note: C:\Users\z565719\AndroidStudioProjects\DrescherBluetoothCanCom\app\src\main\java\z550583\com\navigationdrawer\MainActivity.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
25 errors

:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:

  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
   Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

  BUILD FAILED

  Total time: 1 mins 40.139 secs

I don't know where the problem is because if I try to run the app with his laptop (with his older Android Studio ..) the app works!

Can someone interpret the error

```
 :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.)
```

**UPDATE**

@AshishRanjan asked for the file. Here is my ConnectFragment.java:

```
public class ConnectFragment extends Fragment {
private View rootView;

private Toolbar mToolbar;

private BluetoothComService bluetoothComService;
private boolean isBound = false;

private TextView tvDiConDi;
private ProgressBar pb;
private int CurrentInitProgress = 0;
private int PastInitProgress = 0;
private boolean connectionDetailClicked;
private ImageView ivConnectionDetail;

private ToggleButton tglConnect;

private EditText eTBaudRate;
private EditText eTDbcName;

private LinearLayout LLShowDetail;
private LinearLayout LLConnectToggle;

private LinearLayout LLBaudRate;
private UserDatabaseAdapter userDatabaseAdapter;
private HashMap data;

private ConnectThread connectThread;
private boolean displayThreadLoop = true;

private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        BluetoothComService.LocalBinder binder = (BluetoothComService.LocalBinder) service;
        bluetoothComService = binder.getService();
        isBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        isBound = false;
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Bindet an den BluetoothService
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), BluetoothComService.class);
    getActivity().bindService(intent, mConnection, getActivity().getApplicationContext().BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_connect, container, false);

    tvDiConDi = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_display_connect_description);
    ivConnectionDetail = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.arrow_connection_details);
    pb = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar_connect);
    pb.setProgress(StateSingleton.getInstance().getProgressConnectState());

    eTBaudRate = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edit_baud_rate);
    eTDbcName = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edit_dbc_name);

    LLBaudRate = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_baud_rate);
    LLShowDetail = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_show_detail);
    LLConnectToggle = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_connect_toggle);

    tglConnect = (ToggleButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.connect_toggle);
    tglConnect.setChecked(StateSingleton.getInstance().getTglConnectState());
    tglConnect.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);

    userDatabaseAdapter = new UserDatabaseAdapter(getActivity());
    data = userDatabaseAdapter.getFragmentData(InfoSingleton.getInstance().getUserName());

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);

    //if (data.get(userDatabaseAdapter.ACCESS_NAME) == 1) {
    //    LLBaudRate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    //}

    int ersterInteger = (int) data.get(UserDatabaseAdapter.ACCESS_NAME);
    if (ersterInteger == 1){
        LLBaudRate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

The last if (which is now commented) is where I got my error:

data.get(userDatabaseAdapter.ACCESS_NAME) == 1

The hint from Android Studio is:

The static member 'z550583.com.sql.UserDatabaseAdapter.ACCESS_NAME' accessed via instance reference. Shows references to static methods and fields via class instance rather than a class itself.

But the same hint is also shown in the older Android Studio version. So I'm not sure if this is the only problem.

Comment: you've errors in your code, please share the files in which you're getting the errors, like `ConnectFragment.java` for the above error.

Comment: Can you just install the app afresh? Uninstall the older version?

Comment: I added a answer with the code @AshishRanjan ! But I'm supposed to work with the new version

Comment: you can add the code to the question itself instead of posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that, your `data` is a `HashMap` and the `get` method of the `HashMap` returns an `Object` if you don't define the type of the `value` , so you need to parse the value to `int` before comparing it with `1`.

You can do it like this :

```
int yourInteger= (int)data.get(userDatabaseAdapter.ACCESS_NAME);
if(yourInteger == 1){
    //do something
}
```

**OR**

You can define the type of your value. If you'll define the type as `V` then the `get` method will return an object of type `V` as documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get(java.lang.Object)).

So in your case, you can define the object type of the `key` and `value` in your `HashMap` with generics like this :

```
HashMap<String,Integer> data;
```

instead of :

```
HashMap data;
```

Comment: you're right, Thanks! That's definetly one problem.   BUT .. How is it possible that it worked in his AS version and in mine not ?!?! I didn't change the code so it's exactly the same and in his case it worked and the app runs perfectly on the Android device. But in my case, I'm not able to upload it on the device! Where is the problem?

Comment: that is because you changed JDK version from 1.7 to 1.8 and it doesn't throw any such errors in 1.7, try switching back to 1.7 and it will work, just tried on my pc.

Comment: here's an answer to the same problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155907/classcast-error-java-7-vs-java-8